# Verifier GSON TypeAdapter

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

Process: com.microland.mr.newbalance, PID: 19821
    java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.gson.Gson: com.google.gson.TypeAdapter com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(boolean) failed to verify: com.google.gson.TypeAdapter com.google.gson.Gson.doubleAdapter(boolean): [0xA] returning 'Precise Reference: com.google.gson.Gson$1', but expected from declaration 'Reference: com.google.gson.TypeAdapter' (declaration of 'com.google.gson.Gson' appears in /data/app/com.microland.mr.newbalance-2/base.apk:classes4.dex)
        at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonConverterFactory.java:42)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.di.AppModule.provideNBService(AppModule.java:44)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.di.AppModule_ProvideNBServiceFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideNBServiceFactory.java:18)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.di.AppModule_ProvideNBServiceFactory.get(AppModule_ProvideNBServiceFactory.java:8)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.repository.ProcessRepository_Factory.get(ProcessRepository_Factory.java:17)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.repository.ProcessRepository_Factory.get(ProcessRepository_Factory.java:8)
        at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.di.DaggerAppComponent$ViewModelSubComponentImpl.injectMainActivityViewModel(DaggerAppComponent.java:2509)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.di.DaggerAppComponent$ViewModelSubComponentImpl.mainActivityViewModel(DaggerAppComponent.java:2390)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.viewModel.NBViewModelFactory.lambda$new$14(NBViewModelFactory.java:43)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.viewModel.-$$Lambda$NBViewModelFactory$P6KaEOYLZYfZ5vN_rU6wzRALeUU.call(lambda)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.viewModel.NBViewModelFactory.create(NBViewModelFactory.java:66)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:135)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:103)
        at com.microland.mr.newbalance.view.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6704)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2683)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1530)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6304)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Comment: Can you provide a better description? Try to include what you are trying to achieve and what is happening

Comment: App throws runtime error when I build apk and install it and run.. if I run directly on Android device app works fine